# Android Eclipse LocalDate cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

I am working with Android Eclipse ADT and Java Compiler 1.7, getting:

```
LocalDate cannot be resolved to a type
```

Here is my code:

```
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (1970, 1, 20); // Birth date
LocalDate now = new LocalDate(); // Today's date
Period period = new Period(birthdate, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalDate` is introduced in Java 8 so there is no cuch class in java 7.
You have to change to `java.util.Date` if you are using java 7 or you have to use a java 8 compiler.

For more informations read the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: so what i have to do now ?

Comment: if you use it for Android, please consider this library:
```https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP```